# Adding another parameter to each value in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code,

```
$values = array('a' => 'aa', 'b' => 'bb', 'c' => 'cc');
foreach ($values as $part1 => $part2) {
    echo $part1;
    echo $part2;
    }
```

How can I add another parameter to each value in the array, something like this?

```
$values = array('a' => 'aa' => 'aaa', 'b' => 'bb' => 'bbb', 'c' => 'cc' => 'ccc');
foreach ($values as $part1 => $part2 => $part3) {
    echo $part1; 
    echo $part2;
    echo $part3;
    }
```

Ty!;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I think you're heading in the direction of having subarrays.  Here's an example:

```
$values = array(
    'a' => 
        array( 'aa', 'aaa' ),
    'b' => 
        array( 'bb', 'bbb')
    //etc
);

var_dump($values);
```

**Edit**

To output, just have a two stage loop:

```
foreach($values as $k => $v) {
    echo($k . ':<br>'); // Will output the keys from above
    if(is_array($v)) {
        foreach($v as $i => $j)              // The value is an array, so iterate 
            echo(' &nbsp; ' . $j . '<br>');  // over all sub-elements 

    } else
        echo(' &nbsp; ' . $v . '<br>');
}
```

Comment: Ty very much, this is what I want, did not know it's possible. How do I call them, output them? TY

Comment: I have edited my response, see above.

Answer (score 2):

That isnt legal in PHP, since what you assign is key => value.

What you actually want is a multidimensional array, as such:

```
$values = array(
 array('a','aa','aaa'),
 array('b','bb','bbb')
 );

foreach($values as $value) //Loop through all values
{
 foreach($value as $v) //Loop through each individual value 
 {
   echo $v . ' ,' ;
 }
 echo '<br />';
}
```

To make the structure more clear you can use the `print_r` function to visualise the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $part1.$part2;
```

is what you're looking for?

Although your question is tooooooo vague and I'd prefer to close it instead of answering but here is another *guess*

```
$number = 3;
$values = array('a', 'b', 'c');
foreach ($values as $char) {
  for ($i=1;$i<=$number;$i++)
    echo str_repeat($char,$i),"\n";
  }
}
```